# Store label information into history table | Swift | Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Store label information into history table | Swift | Xcode
If someone can help me with this. So basically what this application does is, it uses azure cognitive services to convert a picture into text and display it in the second screen when analyze is pressed, I want this information to be stored in the third view as a history. Can anyone help in achieving this? Very new in swift, so trying to figure out stuff. Thanks in advance.

Screenshot of the app main storyboard, to clarify what I am asking:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So all you really need is a data structure that allows you to store  your data and allow it to be passed between view controllers.  The simple approach would be to have:

```
struct PictureDetail {
  photo: UIImage
  text: String
}
```

Depending on the volume/size of images, you'd probably better actually holding the photos as files and just keeping the file path in the struct and have a calculated property that retrieves it from disk:

```
struct PictureDetail {
  photoPath: URL
  text: String
  photo: UIImage {
    // load photo from URL & return 
  }
}
```

The you need some form of collection to hold all your data and to allow it to be injected into wherever it is needed

```
class DataModel {
  var pictureData: [PictureDetail] = []

  func addPictureDetail(picture: UIImage, text: String) {
    //save picture to disk and obtain URL
    pictureData.append(PictureDetail(url: url, text: text)
}
```

Then instantiate the data model in your initial view controller

```
let dataModel = DataModel()
```

And then have a DataModel property in the other VCs, and inject the value during your `prepare(for segue: IUSegue)` method.

Comment: so i have mentioned that code in my resultviewcontroller, where images are converted into text and data is shown into two labels, now in my history view controller where i want my text to store as a table view, what should i do?

Comment: You don't store data in a tableView - you store data in a data structure, and use that to populate the tableview whenever it needs to be displayed.  As described above, set the dataModel property of your results controller equal to the ones from your other view controllers and use its array to provide the the data in your tableView.